# JQuery append to select with an array

Tags: jquery, select, append, each

very simple but guess what, not for me.  I have a comma separated list like this: Option1,Option2,Option3 that I want to append to a `<select>` so it becomes `<select><option>Option1</option><option>Option2</option><option>Option3</option></select>`

I can "split" the list like this (inside a function that gets the list):

```
var optionsarray = $(this).val().split(',');

    $(optionsarray).each(function(i){
        var seloption = '<option value="'+optionsarray[i]+'">'+optionsarray[i]+'</option>'; 
    });
```

But now how do I append `seloption` to my select list.  If I put

```
$('#selecttoappendto').append('<option value="'+optionsarray[i]+'">'+optionsarray[i]+'</option>');
```

or

```
$('#selecttoappendto').append(seloption);
```

inside the each loop nothing happens.  Take it outside the each I can append say `optionsarray[0]`, or `optionsarray[1]` etc. but I cannot get to append `optionsarray[i]` which ever way I do it (inside or outside the each).  Help please - thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with an empty string, you can build a string in the loop usingt `+=`. Then `.append()` the string.

```
var optionsarray = $(this).val().split(',');

var seloption = "";

$.each(optionsarray,function(i){
    seloption += '<option value="'+optionsarray[i]+'">'+optionsarray[i]+'</option>'; 
});

$('#selecttoappendto').append(seloption);
```

or another option would be to build the elements separately, store them in a container, then append them from the container.

```
var optionsarray = $(this).val().split(',');

var temp_sel = $('<select>');

$.each(optionsarray,function(i){
    temp_sel.append('<option>',{text:optionsarray[i],
                                value:optionsarray[i]
                                });
});

temp_sel.children().appendTo('#selecttoappendto');
```

---

*Fixed missing `()` after `children`.*

Comment: many thanks, perfect, I "know" about += - bit like .= in PHP but could not get it to work, assume that is why you declare var seloption = ""; first

Comment: @Russell: Yes exactly, you need to initialize it with an empty string before you `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I wrote and use; it's a little faster than the solution user113716 gave, because you're skipping creating the temp select, all those appends to that temp select (even if it is a DOM fragment, it still takes *some* time), and you're also skipping the .children() find and unwrapping at the end for that final append.

```
// Appends multiple elements all at once; maintains chaining
$.fn.appendAll = function ($eleArr) {
    var numEles = $eleArr.length
    ,    $useEle = new $();
    if (numEles) {
        while (numEles--) {
            $useEle = $eleArr[numEles].add($useEle);
        }
        return $(this).append($useEle);
    }
};

// Prepends multiple elements all at once; maintains chaining
$.fn.prependAll = function ($eleArr) {
    var numEles = $eleArr.length
    ,    $useEle = new $();
    if (numEles) {
        while (numEles--) {
            $useEle = $eleArr[numEles].add($useEle);
        }
        return $(this).prepend($useEle);
    }
};
```

So:

```
var optsArr = $(this).val().split(','),
    $options = [],
    thisOption;

$.each(optsArr, function(i) {
    thisOption = '<option value="' + optsArr[i] + '">' + optsArr[i] + '</option>';
    $options.push($(thisOption));
});

$yourSelect.appendAll(optsArr);
```

I actually wrote those plugins for exactly this; doing it this way, I build a 1500+ option select in under 250 ms.  :D

Comment: In case anyone's wondering it should be `$yourSelect.appendAll($options);`

Comment: I'm guessing it was different in 2012 but these days the built-in `.append` can also take an array, so it behaves just like the `.appendAll` here and you don't need this any more (same deal with `.prepend`). +1 for making it work back in the day, though.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`.append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) can take an array these days (dunno what it was like in 2012), so this works too:

```
let vals = $(this).val().split(',');
$('#myselect').append(vals.map(v => $('<option/>').text(v).attr({value:v})));
```

The [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/#jQuery-map-array-callback) function can also be used. It will create a jQuery array that has an `.appendTo`:

```
$.map($(this).val().split(','), v=>$('<option/>').text(v).attr({value:v}))
  .appendTo('#myselect');
```