# jQuery.each() build set of jQuery Objects, append after

Tags: jquery, append, each

I want to run one single `.append()` after my `.each()` for efficiency. I tried to build out my set of objects and it won't run. It's similar to this question, except I'm building a jQuery object instead of a string.

[JQuery append to select with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969754/jquery-append-to-select-with-an-array)

## HTML

`<select></select>`

## jQuery

```
var items = ['apple','pear','taco','orange'],
    options = '';

jQuery.each(items, function(i, fruit){
    options += jQuery('<option/>', {
        value: fruit,
        text: fruit
    });
}); //added missing ');'

jQuery('select').append(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not concatenate objects, your code results in `[object Object][object Object]..`. Also you are missing `)` for closing `each` method.

```
$.each(items, function (i, fruit) {
    options += '<option value=' + fruit + '>' + fruit + '</option>';
});

$('select').append(options);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NxB6Z/

Update:

```
var items = ['apple', 'pear', 'taco', 'orange'],
    options = [];

jQuery.each(items, function (i, fruit) {
    options.push($('<option/>', {
        value: fruit,
        text: fruit
    }));
});

jQuery('select').append(options);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HyzWG/

Comment: So, there's no way to do it with an object?

Comment: You can't append an array. So this solution doesn't work. I'll go with the string approach, unless you know of a way to make an array work without a loop.

Comment: @PatrickRobertSheaO'Connor _"You can't append an array"_, that's not true, it works in the fiddle.

Comment: When I try, i get `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]` as the error. When I `console.log(options)` I see that it's a group of options. Not sure what else could be the difference.

Comment: Okay, I discovered why this isn't working. I'm on jQuery 1.7.2 and this code doesn't work in that version.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be an object?  Why not just append to a string, then append that string afterwards?

```
$.each(items, function(i,fruit){
    options += "<option value='"+fruit+"'>"+fruit+"</option>";
});
```